# Problema Peticiones Http Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, http, cors

Tengo mi api rest hecha en nodejs (express)lo cual esta en local http://localhost:3000, mi configuracion de cors de
mi api rest 
es

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```

pues en mi aplicacion de ionic cuando inicio **ionic serve -c** en mi navegador de mi pc funcionan todas las peticiones Http lo cual yo uso **HttpClientModule** cuando ya lo pruebo en 
[IonicDev App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.ionic.devapp&fbclid=IwAR13rZFXx9zZqEE29W3kyGdm2mZBu9dXC72GvWugQsW7HGq92vEoHJfAJyI) o en el Emulador de Android studios recibo un error

```
{
 “data”: null,
 “status”: 0,
 “config”: {
   “method”: “GET”,
   “transformRequest”: [null], 
   “transformResponse”: [null],
   “Accept”: “ application / json ”,
   “ Content-Type ”:“ application / json ”,
   “ url ”:“
```

también he probado creando un proxy en **ionic.config.json**
pero me sigue lanzando el mismo error

```
"proxies": [
  {
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "http://aqui.com/api"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apunta a la IP del servidor que aloja tu servicio web en lugar de apuntar a localhost. 
Tu cliente ionic está haciendo peticiones a si mismo.
Al desplegar la aplicación de Ionic en un dispositivo, el cliente y el servidor están en máquinas distintas.

Comment: segun lo que tengo entendido cuando trabajo con ionicDevApp trabaja coomo localhost:8080 y como lo ve inseguro ya que proviene del localhost lo bloquea

Comment: No te compliques diseccionando de esa forma, en la computadora donde esta tu servidor obtén la ip en consola con _ipconfig_ y haz las peticiones de tu emulador a esa dirección, prueba escribiendo esa dirección en un navegador en otro dispositivo para ver si esta bien configurado tu servidor

Answer (score 0):

reemplaza tu endpoint principal en tu frontend  http://localhost:3000 ---> http://192.168.1.100:3000 donde (192.168.1.100 es la ip donde esta funcionando tu backend)